# Subset data in a large list based on filename of the dataframes in the list

Tags: r, list, subset, filenames

I'm working with a large list that contains 450 dataframes. I'll make an example of the **names of the dataframes**:

```
ALL_SM51_SE1_hourly, ALL_SM201_SE1_hourly, ALL_SM501_SE1_hourly
ALL_SM51_SE2_hourly, ALL_SM201_SE2_hourly, ALL_SM501_SE2_hourly
...................................................................
ALL_SM51_SE150_hourly, ALL_SM201_SE150_hourly, ALL_SM501_SE150_hourly
```

The dataframes contain measured soil moisture data at different depths (5cm, 20cm, 50cm, **represented by "SM51, SM201, SM501" in the filenames**) and there are **150 sensors** (**represented by the "SE1, SE2, SE3, ..." in the filename**) which is why I have 450 dataframes that are stored in a list.

What I would like to do: I want to create a new list (make a subset) for each sensor that then contains 3 elements. So I wanna have a list for SE1, SE2, SE3, ..., SE150 with the corresponding measuring depths.

I already searched for an appropriate answer to my question but I only found answers that subset data by specific values but **I want to subset by the filenames**.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Is the `"ALL_SM_201,SE2_hourly"` an error, i.e. it is actually `"ALL_SM201_SE2_hourly"`?

Comment: @jay.sf Oh yeah, sorry! I changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions you may identify unique sensors `un.se` which you can `paste` to `new.names`. The original list `lst` then can be `split` into unique sensors, `ordered` and converted into `data.frame`s.

```
un.se <- gsub(".*SE(\\d+).*", "\\1", names(lst))
new.names <- paste0("SE", unique(un.se))
tmp <- setNames(split(lst, un.se), paste0("SE", unique(un.se)))
res <- lapply(tmp, function(x) {
  nm <- gsub(".*SM(\\d+).*", "\\1", names(x))
  setNames(lapply(x[order(nm)], data.frame), paste0("d", gsub("1$", "", nm)))
  })
```

*Explanation `gsub`-regex:*

In the regex `.*` looks for any "character-until", then we have `SE` literally. Now we use grouping inside parentheses `(` `)`, where we look with `\\d+` for one or more occurrences of a number or `d`igit. In the second `gsub`-argument `\\1` does a back-reference on the first group (that in the parentheses) to replace the whole string. E.g. resulting `un.se` is the number found after each `SE` in each string (see: https://regex101.com/r/zuO8Ts/1; and note that we need double escapes `\\` in R).

This lists each sensor with data frames for each depth in sublists.

### Result

```
res
# $SE1
# $SE1$d5
#   x1 x2 x3
# 1  1  2  3
# 
# $SE1$d20
#   x1 x2 x3
# 1  1  2  3
# 
# $SE1$d50
#   x1 x2 x3
# 1  1  2  3
# 
# 
# $SE2
# $SE2$d5
#   x1 x2 x3
# 1  1  2  3
# 
# $SE2$d20
#   x1 x2 x3
# 1  1  2  3
# 
# $SE2$d50
#   x1 x2 x3
# 1  1  2  3
```

---

*Toy data*

```
lst <- list(ALL_SM51_SE1_hourly = list(x1 = 1, x2 = 2, x3 = 3), ALL_SM201_SE1_hourly = list(
    x1 = 1, x2 = 2, x3 = 3), ALL_SM501_SE1_hourly = list(x1 = 1, 
    x2 = 2, x3 = 3), ALL_SM51_SE2_hourly = list(x1 = 1, x2 = 2, 
    x3 = 3), ALL_SM201_SE2_hourly = list(x1 = 1, x2 = 2, x3 = 3), 
    ALL_SM501_SE2_hourly = list(x1 = 1, x2 = 2, x3 = 3))
```

Comment: Wow, that worked. Thank you so much for your quick and helpful reply!

You've already done enough but I'm new to R and this seems very advanced to me. Could you potentially explain what exactly you did?

Comment: I especially don't get what the expressions `".*SE(\\d+).*", "\\1"` do.

Comment: @Phil added some explanation, does that make sense?