# Summarize hourly data to daily data in a list in R

Tags: r, aggregate, lapply, summarize

I'm trying to summarize hourly measurement data to daily data for every element in a list.

List looks like this:

```
SE104:List of 3
  ..$ d20:List of 11
  .. ..$ 2009:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  .. ..$ 2010:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2010-01-01" "2010-01-01" "2010-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  .. ..$ 2011:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2011-01-01" "2011-01-01" "2011-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  .. ..$ 2012:'data.frame': 8784 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8784], format: "2012-01-01" "2012-01-01" "2012-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8784] 43.1 43 42.8 42.7 42.7 ...
  .. ..$ 2013:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2013-01-01" "2013-01-01" "2013-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  .. ..$ 2014:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 37.2 37.2 37.3 37.2 37.1 ...
  .. ..$ 2015:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 37.3 37.3 37.3 37.3 37.3 ...
  .. ..$ 2016:'data.frame': 8784 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8784], format: "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8784] 36 36 36 36 35.9 ...
  .. ..$ 2017:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 32.9 32.9 32.9 32.9 32.9 ...
  .. ..$ 2018:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 35 35.1 35.2 35.2 35.2 ...
  .. ..$ 2019:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2019-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2019-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  ..$ d50:List of 11
  .. ..$ 2009:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  .. ..$ 2010:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2010-01-01" "2010-01-01" "2010-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  .. ..$ 2011:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2011-01-01" "2011-01-01" "2011-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  .. ..$ 2012:'data.frame': 8784 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8784], format: "2012-01-01" "2012-01-01" "2012-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8784] 39.8 39.6 39.4 39.3 39.3 ...
  .. ..$ 2013:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2013-01-01" "2013-01-01" "2013-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  .. ..$ 2014:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 32.7 32.7 32.8 32.7 32.7 ...
  .. ..$ 2015:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 33.2 33.2 33.2 33.2 33.2 ...
  .. ..$ 2016:'data.frame': 8784 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8784], format: "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8784] 31.9 31.9 31.9 31.9 31.9 ...
  .. ..$ 2017:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 27.9 27.9 27.9 27.9 27.9 ...
  .. ..$ 2018:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 29.2 29.2 29.2 29.2 29.2 ...
  .. ..$ 2019:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2019-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2019-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  ..$ d5 :List of 11
  .. ..$ 2009:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  .. ..$ 2010:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2010-01-01" "2010-01-01" "2010-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  .. ..$ 2011:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2011-01-01" "2011-01-01" "2011-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  .. ..$ 2012:'data.frame': 8784 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8784], format: "2012-01-01" "2012-01-01" "2012-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8784] 58.4 58.4 58.3 58.2 58.2 ...
  .. ..$ 2013:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2013-01-01" "2013-01-01" "2013-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  .. ..$ 2014:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 47.4 47.4 47.4 47.4 47.4 ...
  .. ..$ 2015:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 49 49.1 49 49.1 49.1 ...
  .. ..$ 2016:'data.frame': 8784 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8784], format: "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8784] 43.7 43.7 43.7 43.8 43.7 ...
  .. ..$ 2017:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 39.1 39.2 39.1 39.2 39.2 ...
  .. ..$ 2018:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 45.8 46 46 45.9 45.7 ...
  .. ..$ 2019:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2019-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2019-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
 $ SE105:List of 3
  ..$ d20:List of 11
  .. ..$ 2009:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" "2009-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  .. ..$ 2010:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2010-01-01" "2010-01-01" "2010-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 45.4 45.2 45 44.9 44.8 ...
  .. ..$ 2011:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2011-01-01" "2011-01-01" "2011-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 39.6 39.6 39.6 39.6 39.6 ...
  .. ..$ 2012:'data.frame': 8784 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8784], format:
```

So you can see that my list has multiple levels. First level is a large list that contains 150 lists. Each list of those 150 lists contains 3 lists (d20, d50, d5) which contain 11 dataframes for each year from 2009-2019.

Each dataframe stored in the list looks like this:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 
14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 
14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 14245, 
14245, 14245, 14246, 14246, 14246, 14246, 14246, 14246), class = "Date"), 
    SWC = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
    NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
    NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN)), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")
```

**I want to summarize the data so that I get one value for each day, I was able to do this for just one dataframe that I subsetted but I can't do it for every element in the list.** I think I have to use lapply() but I can't figure out how to do it. This is what it should look like:

```
        Date mean_SWC
1 2009-01-01      NaN
2 2009-01-02      NaN
```

I'd appreciate some help! A user helped me out with the lapply() function in another question already but it looks like I didn't understand how to use it, as I can't do it here. So in case someone can help and does indeed use lapply() I'd appreciate if one could explain it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nested list (sensors) of lists (measurements) of lists (data frames), where each of them wants an `lapply`.

I'm sure there's also an `rapply` solution, possible though.

Since I've answered one of your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60926815/6574038) I assume you want to do aggregation by each sensor.

You could refine the `lapply` approach by collapsing some of the sub-lists. You could therefore consider e.g. these three solutions.

### Solution 1

Yielding a list structure similar to the original one, just days `aggregate`d for each year.

```
res1 <- lapply(dat, function(se)
  lapply(se, function(m)
    lapply(m, function(d) 
      aggregate(swc ~ date, d, sum))))
```

**Structure of resulting list**

```
str(res1, 3)
# List of 3
#  $ SE104:List of 3
#   ..$ d20:List of 11
#   .. ..$ 2009:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2010:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2011:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2012:'data.frame':   366 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2013:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2014:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2015:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2016:'data.frame':   366 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2017:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2018:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2019:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ d50:List of 11
#   .. ..$ 2009:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2010:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2011:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2012:'data.frame':   366 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2013:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2014:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2015:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2016:'data.frame':   366 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2017:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2018:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2019:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ d5 :List of 11
#   .. ..$ 2009:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2010:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2011:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2012:'data.frame':   366 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2013:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2014:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2015:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2016:'data.frame':   366 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2017:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2018:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2019:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ SE105:List of 3
#   ..$ d20:List of 11
#   .. ..$ 2009:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2010:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ 2011:'data.frame':   365 obs. of  2 variables:
# [...]
```

**Sample data frame of result**

```
head(res1$SE104$d20$`2009`)
#         date        swc
# 1 2009-01-01   7.642943
# 2 2009-01-02   2.251837
# 3 2009-01-03  -2.579394
# 4 2009-01-04   5.265464
# 5 2009-01-05  -2.891591
# 6 2009-01-06 -12.054497
```

### Solution 1 (enhanced)

Enhanced version of solution 1, that bypasses errors from `aggregate` when `ncol(x) == 0` using `tryCatch()`.

```
dat2 <- dat  ## copy of dat
## intentionally make one data frame of nrow == 0
dat2$SE104$d20$`2009` <- data.frame(date=as.Date(character()),
                                    swc=double())

res1.enh <- lapply(dat2, function(se)
  lapply(se, function(m)
    setNames(lapply(1:length(m), function(d) 
      tryCatch(aggregate(swc ~ date, m[[d]], function(x) sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)),
               error=function(e) {
                 ## mimicks aggregate result with NA column for swc
                 y <- as.numeric(names(m)[d])
                 cbind.data.frame(
                   date=as.Date(as.character(seq(ISOdate(y, 1, 1, 0), 
                                                 ISOdate(y, 12, 31, 0), by="day"))),
                   swc=NA)
                 })), names(m))))
```

**Example result when ncol == 0**

```
head(res1.enh$SE104$d20$`2009`)
#         date swc
# 1 2009-01-01  NA
# 2 2009-01-02  NA
# 3 2009-01-03  NA
# 4 2009-01-04  NA
# 5 2009-01-05  NA
# 6 2009-01-06  NA
```

**Normal result*

```
head(res1.enh$SE104$d20$`2010`)
#         date       swc
# 1 2010-01-01 -1.001692
# 2 2010-01-02 -2.531776
# 3 2010-01-03  6.036390
# 4 2010-01-04 -5.470039
# 5 2010-01-05 -1.659984
# 6 2010-01-06 -8.495954
```

### Solution 2

Like solution 1, with years collapsed.

```
res2 <- lapply(dat, function(se)
  lapply(se, function(m)
    aggregate(swc ~ date, do.call(rbind, m), sum)))
```

**Structure of resulting list**

```
str(res2)
# List of 3
#  $ SE104:List of 3
#   ..$ d20:'data.frame':   4017 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ date: Date[1:4017], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-02" "2009-01-03" ...
#   .. ..$ swc : num [1:4017] 7.64 2.25 -2.58 5.27 -2.89 ...
#   ..$ d50:'data.frame':   4017 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ date: Date[1:4017], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-02" "2009-01-03" ...
#   .. ..$ swc : num [1:4017] -7.658 -10.792 2.617 0.811 4.529 ...
#   ..$ d5 :'data.frame':   4017 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ date: Date[1:4017], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-02" "2009-01-03" ...
#   .. ..$ swc : num [1:4017] 2.52 2.01 7.26 5.33 -5.01 ...
#  $ SE105:List of 3
#   ..$ d20:'data.frame':   4017 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ date: Date[1:4017], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-02" "2009-01-03" ...
#   .. ..$ swc : num [1:4017] 5.88 -5.2 -7.11 2.57 2.29 ...
#   ..$ d50:'data.frame':   4017 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ date: Date[1:4017], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-02" "2009-01-03" ...
#   .. ..$ swc : num [1:4017] -10.09 -6.48 4.57 -7.04 -7.81 ...
#   ..$ d5 :'data.frame':   4017 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ date: Date[1:4017], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-02" "2009-01-03" ...
#   .. ..$ swc : num [1:4017] -0.329 -4.42 -1.826 -7.249 1.083 ...
#  $ SE106:List of 3
#   ..$ d20:'data.frame':   4017 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ date: Date[1:4017], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-02" "2009-01-03" ...
#   .. ..$ swc : num [1:4017] 4.905 -4.207 2.128 0.121 -2.668 ...
#   ..$ d50:'data.frame':   4017 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ date: Date[1:4017], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-02" "2009-01-03" ...
#   .. ..$ swc : num [1:4017] 4.092 -4.983 -7.234 -6.362 -0.135 ...
#   ..$ d5 :'data.frame':   4017 obs. of  2 variables:
#   .. ..$ date: Date[1:4017], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-02" "2009-01-03" ...
#   .. ..$ swc : num [1:4017] 2.13 4.26 10.59 0.56 2.36 ...
```

**Sample data frame of result**

```
head(res2$SE104$d20)
#         date        swc
# 1 2009-01-01   7.642943
# 2 2009-01-02   2.251837
# 3 2009-01-03  -2.579394
# 4 2009-01-04   5.265464
# 5 2009-01-05  -2.891591
# 6 2009-01-06 -12.054497
```

### Solution 3

A kind of wide format of solution 2.

```
res3 <- lapply(dat, function(se) {
  tmp <- lapply(se, function(m) do.call(data.frame, aggregate(swc ~ date, do.call(rbind, m), sum)))
  data.frame(date=el(tmp)[["date"]], setNames(mapply(`[`, tmp, 2), names(se)))
  })
```

**Structure of resulting list**

```
str(res3)
# List of 3
#  $ SE104:'data.frame':    4017 obs. of  4 variables:
#   ..$ date: Date[1:4017], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-02" "2009-01-03" ...
#   ..$ d20 : num [1:4017] 7.64 2.25 -2.58 5.27 -2.89 ...
#   ..$ d50 : num [1:4017] -7.658 -10.792 2.617 0.811 4.529 ...
#   ..$ d5  : num [1:4017] 2.52 2.01 7.26 5.33 -5.01 ...
#  $ SE105:'data.frame':    4017 obs. of  4 variables:
#   ..$ date: Date[1:4017], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-02" "2009-01-03" ...
#   ..$ d20 : num [1:4017] 5.88 -5.2 -7.11 2.57 2.29 ...
#   ..$ d50 : num [1:4017] -10.09 -6.48 4.57 -7.04 -7.81 ...
#   ..$ d5  : num [1:4017] -0.329 -4.42 -1.826 -7.249 1.083 ...
#  $ SE106:'data.frame':    4017 obs. of  4 variables:
#   ..$ date: Date[1:4017], format: "2009-01-01" "2009-01-02" "2009-01-03" ...
#   ..$ d20 : num [1:4017] 4.905 -4.207 2.128 0.121 -2.668 ...
#   ..$ d50 : num [1:4017] 4.092 -4.983 -7.234 -6.362 -0.135 ...
#   ..$ d5  : num [1:4017] 2.13 4.26 10.59 0.56 2.36 ...
```

**Heads of the three data frames in the resulting list**

```
lapply(res3, head)
# $SE104
#         date        d20         d50        d5
# 1 2009-01-01   7.642943  -7.6576879  2.520563
# 2 2009-01-02   2.251837 -10.7916635  2.012231
# 3 2009-01-03  -2.579394   2.6173333  7.260413
# 4 2009-01-04   5.265464   0.8107366  5.327772
# 5 2009-01-05  -2.891591   4.5289522 -5.014450
# 6 2009-01-06 -12.054497  -5.9274899  1.441439
# 
# $SE105
#         date       d20        d50         d5
# 1 2009-01-01  5.880239 -10.093960 -0.3288049
# 2 2009-01-02 -5.196587  -6.478163 -4.4196227
# 3 2009-01-03 -7.114667   4.568871 -1.8259147
# 4 2009-01-04  2.565384  -7.039717 -7.2492291
# 5 2009-01-05  2.289701  -7.808063  1.0832635
# 6 2009-01-06 -1.674715   4.360558  2.2994494
# 
# $SE106
#         date        d20        d50        d5
# 1 2009-01-01  4.9053760  4.0917553  2.132417
# 2 2009-01-02 -4.2074579 -4.9825570  4.256667
# 3 2009-01-03  2.1284944 -7.2339473 10.588332
# 4 2009-01-04  0.1208879 -6.3617098  0.560269
# 5 2009-01-05 -2.6676826 -0.1350602  2.364006
# 6 2009-01-06 -3.0595029  7.9359285  6.903543
```

---

*Toy data:*

```
dat <- setNames(replicate(3, setNames(replicate(3, setNames(lapply(2009:2019, function(y) {
  d <- expand.grid(date=as.Date(as.character(seq(ISOdate(y, 1, 1, 0), ISOdate(y, 12, 31, 0), by="day"))), 
                   hour=1:24)
  d$swc <- rnorm(nrow(d))
  d[order(d$date), -2]
  }), 2009:2019), simplify=F), c("d20", "d50", "d5")), simplify=F), c("SE104", "SE105", "SE106"))
```

Comment: Thanks again for your effort jay.sf. I like the first solution best because it keeps the years separate from one another but unfortunately it doesn't work. I still get the following error: 

`error in aggregate.data.frame(mf[1L], mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : no rows to aggregate`

Comment: I looked up the error and found that it occurs when an object has zero rows. I checked that with `ncol()` but the last level (dataframe) that I access via `lapply()` has 2 while all the other levels (list) have zero. Maybe it stops the `lapply()` right in the beginning because the other levels of the list have zero columns? It doesn't make sense to me because it should obviously only care about the last level which are the three dataframes stored in the last list, but maybe that's the issue.

Comment: Sorry obviously I meant  `nrow` instead of `ncol` in the comment above ;).

Comment: @Phil Well in that case we could use catch 22 and use `tryCatch()`! Please see edit **Solution 1 (enhanced)** and try it with your data.

Comment: @Phil For understanding: I changed the `lapply(m, .)` into `lapply(1:length(m), .)` so that it now loops over numbers instead of the columns; therefore inside the loop occurs an `m[[d]]` to obtain the subset, where `d` is a number, precisely the number of that sub-list would fail in the `aggregate`. There was a slight error I fixed now.

Comment: Once again, thank you so much for your help, it worked! 

However, there are numerous things I don't understand. 
1. Why do we use `lapply` only three times in the code, even though we have to access the dataframes with the years which are on the 4th level of the whole structure? I thought the program would wanna execute the functions coming after that for the 3rd level then, which would be a list with the depth (d20, d50, d5) of the sensor. 

2. 
I don't really understand what tryCatch does and what the code does after that (except the aggregate line).

Comment: 3. 

In order to learn things like that, do you know anything like an R online course or sth. like that you can recommend? As you know I'm doing data analysis and data preparation and it seems I lack knowledge on how to do that. I thought maybe you learned it that way as well and could potentially recommend something.

Comment: Very welcome @Phil, glad to help. 1. The `lapply`s loop over the levels of the list, the list itself just has 3 levels that are lists. Compare e.g. `names(dat)`, when we want the names of the "first" level, but `lapply(dat, names)` when we want the names of the "second" level. Hence I would speak of the names of the list objects in the first case and the names of the _first_ level in the second case; `aggregate` cares for the data frames. [...]

Comment: [...] 2. Consider `tryCatch` as a sandbox, where in the `error=` argument we define what should happen when the code fails.In this case we want a data frame with `NA` in `swc` for every day of the that fails, and that we get with `d` from the names of `m`. Try to run each `lapply` individually defining e.g. `m <- dat2$SE104` etc. 3. Work through [R-intro](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf), [R Reference Card](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Short-refcard.pdf), [R FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html).

Comment: @Phil Learn to express your data problems in concise R language, research; I recommend using additional packages only when absolutely necessary

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no sample data available, define

```
A = data.frame(Date = c("31.01.2020", "31.01.2020", "31.01.2020"), SWC = c(25, 100, 2))
B = data.frame(Date = c("31.01.2020", "31.01.2020", "31.01.2020"), SWC = c(25, 100, 2))
C = data.frame(Date = c("31.01.2020", "31.01.2020", "31.01.2020"), SWC = c(25, 100, 2))
D = data.frame(Date = c("31.01.2020", "31.01.2020", "31.01.2020"), SWC = c(25, 100, 2))

E = list(A, B)
F2 = list(C, D) 
G = list(E, F2) 
H = list(G, G)
```

This should mimic the nesting structure of your list.

Then one possibility is to use lapply several times in combination with aggregate

```
lapply(H, function(x) 
           lapply(x, function(y) 
                     lapply(y, function(z) 
                              aggregate(SWC~Date, data = z, FUN = function(a) c(mean = mean(a), count = length(a))))))
```

which yields the result

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
        Date SWC.mean SWC.count
1 31.01.2020 42.33333   3.00000

[[1]][[1]][[2]]
        Date SWC.mean SWC.count
1 31.01.2020 42.33333   3.00000


[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]][[1]]
        Date SWC.mean SWC.count
1 31.01.2020 42.33333   3.00000

[[1]][[2]][[2]]
        Date SWC.mean SWC.count
1 31.01.2020 42.33333   3.00000



[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]]
        Date SWC.mean SWC.count
1 31.01.2020 42.33333   3.00000

[[2]][[1]][[2]]
        Date SWC.mean SWC.count
1 31.01.2020 42.33333   3.00000


[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]][[1]]
        Date SWC.mean SWC.count
1 31.01.2020 42.33333   3.00000

[[2]][[2]][[2]]
        Date SWC.mean SWC.count
1 31.01.2020 42.33333   3.00000
```

Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Yeah that is what I meant, sorry I should have extracted sample data where not all values are "NaN".
However, I get the following error: 

 `error in aggregate.data.frame(mf[1L], mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  no rows to aggregate`

Comment: Could this have something to do with the fact that your Date column is of mode factor while mine is mode Date?

Comment: I suppose not. Are you sure that all data.frames in all lists have the same number of columns and column names?

Comment: Yes they do. However, not all data.frames have the same length. Some have 8784 values and some have 8760 values, didnt' see that before.